# Altair line chart adds unwanted extra day at the beginning

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I'm creating a line chart using the data shown in the dataframe. When I do it, Altair counts some of the data in the day prior to the actual starting date. How can I avoid this?

Here is the code that generates the chart:

```
data = df
x_val = 'monthdate(creationTime):T'
y_val = 'count(total):Q'

def line_chart(data, title_chart, x_val, y_val, title_x, title_y):

    lines = (
        alt.Chart(
            data,
            title=title_chart,
        )
        .mark_line(point=alt.OverlayMarkDef())
        .encode(
            x=alt.X(
                x_val,
                title=title_x,
                axis=alt.Axis(grid=False),
            ),
            y=alt.Y(
                y_val,
                title=title_y,
                axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)
            ),
        )
    )

    hover = alt.selection_single(
        fields=[x_val],
        nearest=True,
        on="mouseover",
        empty="none",
    )

    points = lines.transform_filter(hover).mark_circle(size=65)

    tooltips = (
        alt.Chart(data)
        .mark_rule()
        .encode(
            x=x_val,
            y=y_val,
            opacity=alt.condition(hover, alt.value(0.3), alt.value(0)),
            tooltip=[
                alt.Tooltip(x_val, title=title_x),
                alt.Tooltip(y_val, title=title_y),
            ],
        )
        .add_selection(hover)
    )

    final = (lines + points + tooltips).configure_view(strokeWidth=0).interactive()
    return st.altair_chart(final, use_container_width=True)
```

[image: Altair screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this using `df.dt.tz_localize()`. Apparently Altair thinks the dates are UTC by default.

Comment: Yes you need your date strings to be fully-qualified ISO 8601 date strings, or Javascript will parse them as UTC rather than local time. This is mentioned in the issue I linked above https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2540#issuecomment-999043013. Just a tip to include data in your questions (as text) next time and you will be able to get help quicker and more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are experiencing the issue reported here https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2540. There are some more details there but this workaround should fix it for now:

Original shifted plot:

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'reportday': ['2021-11-08', '2021-11-09', '2021-11-10', '2021-11-11','2021-11-12', '2021-11-15','2021-11-16', '2021-11-17', '2021-11-18','2021-11-19'],
    'price': [328.0, 310.0, 301.0, 3330.0, 3278.0, 3200.0, 2189.0, 1701.0, 1698.0, 1703.0],
    'production': [24.75, 16.30, 14.77, 14.10, 27.70, 26.70, 29.05, 19.58, 24.88, 17.35]
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('monthdate(reportday):O', axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=325)),
    y='production'
)
```

[image]

Workaround:

```py
df['reportday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reportday']).dt.strftime('%b %d')

base = alt.Chart(df).encode(x=alt.X('reportday:O', axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=325)))
line =  base.mark_line(color='red').encode(y=alt.Y('price:Q', axis=alt.Axis(grid=True)))
bar = base.mark_bar().encode(y='production:Q')

(bar + line).resolve_scale(y='independent').properties(width=600)
```

[image]

Comment: You could also use `df['reportday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reportday'])` and use the original temporal encoding, in which case Altair takes care of proper date formatting for consumption by vega-lite.  The issue stems from having non-standard date strings in your data and telling Vega-Lite to interpret them as temporal.

Comment: this solution doesn't work for me. I still get the extra day after the to_datetime